# Jboss configuration with grails (ggts)

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss7.x, ggts

How to configure JBOSS with GGTS tool to Deploy Grails application on it.

I have Jboss setup but not able to find from where and how I can add new server and deploy my grails WAR and EAR.

Please help by providing suitable documents and links. ...:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need GGTS for that. Please look at the next plugin `http://grails.org/plugin/jbossas`.
And deploying to the JBoss/WildFly is just copying war-files to `/path/to/jboss-as/standalone/deployments/` folder.

Comment: I'm working(Developing Grails Application) on GGTS, so I need to configure jboss on GGTS 3.6.0 and after configuration need to deploy my grails project on Jboss what I'm searching for...:)

Comment: I said not that you needn't GGTS at all. Please use if you want. I said that you needn't GGTS to solve that problem. That problem only from Grails and Jboss. Please look wider.